# RxAlamofire: Ambiguous reference to member 'json(_:_:parameters:encoding:headers:)'

Tags: rxalamofire

When I try to compile the code below, I get an error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'json(*:*:parameters:encoding:headers:)'

The code was copied and pasted from a RxAlamofire Github repository page

```
import RxSwift
import RxAlamofire

class CurrencyRest {

        static func getJson() {

            let stringURL = "https://api.fixer.io/latest"

            // MARK: NSURLSession simple and fast
            let session = URLSession.init()

            _ = session.rx.json(.get, stringURL)
                .observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)
                .subscribe { print($0) }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, `session.rx.json(url:)` is the way to go, it's from RxCocoa, although for RxAlamofire, you don't have to use URLSession rx extension, instead, use `json(::parameters:encoding:headers:)`, e.g. `json(.get, stringURL)`, which returns an `Observable<Any>` that you can use as JSON.